# How to implement a timeout control for urlllib2.urlopen

Tags: python, timer, timeout, urllib2

How to implement a controlling for urlllib2.urlopen in Python ? I just wanna monitor that if in 5 seconds no xml data return, cut this connection and connect again? Should I use some timer? thx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
urllib2.urlopen("http://www.example.com", timeout=5)
```

Comment: this will cause that the xml data is fetched every 5 seconds?

Comment: Absolutely not. It will try to fetch the data until 5 seconds expired

Comment: when I add the timeout parameter, the python script only fetch data every 3/5 seconds. But when I do not use timeout, it fetch data 1-5 times per second. What is going on? thanks

Answer (score 7):

From the [`urllib2` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)...

> The optional timeout parameter specifies a timeout in seconds for
>   blocking operations like the connection attempt (if not specified, the
>   global default timeout setting will be used). This actually only works
>   for HTTP, HTTPS and FTP connections.

Comment: And if you want to catch the exception, you'll need to catch all of these.. `ssl.SSLError`, `urllib2.URLError`, `socket.timeout`, `socket.error` (possibly I didn't include everything). Some of which wont always be because of timeouts, but you can inspect the exception instance in certain ways to find out, and re-raise if not.