# Identify if a website is taking too long to respond

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to find if a website is taking too long to respond or not.

For example, i need to identify this website as problematic: http://www.lowcostbet.com/

I am trying something like this:

```
print urllib.urlopen("http://www.lowcostbet.com/").getcode()
```

but i am getting `Connection timed out`

My objective is just create a routine to identify what websites are taking too long to load. (e.g. 4 seconds, and cancel the request)

Comment: Is there something wrong with the timeout parameter of `urlopen()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-python-function-call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement a timeout control for urlllib2.urlopen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018007/how-to-implement-a-timeout-control-for-urlllib2-urlopen)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

urlopen from urllib2 package has timeout param.

You can use something like this:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen

TO = 4
website = "http://www.lowcostbet.com/"

try:
    response = urlopen(website, timeout=TO)
except:
    mark_as_not_responsive(website)
```

UPD:

Please, note that using my snippet as-is suck because you'll catch all kind of exceptions, not just timeouts here. And probably, you need to make several tries before marking website as non-responsive.

Answer (score 0):

also, `requests.get` has a timeout kwarg you can pass in.
from the docs:

```
requests.get('http://github.com', timeout=0.001)
```

this will raise an exception, so you probably want to handle that.

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/

Answer (score 0):

The timeout value will be applied to both the **connect** and the **read** timeouts. Specify a tupleif would like to set the values separately:

```
import requests

try:
    r = requests.get('https://github.com', timeout=(6.05, 27))
except requests.Timeout:
    ...
except requests.ConnectionError:
    ...
except requests.HTTPError:
    ... 
except requests.RequestException:
    ...
else:
    print(r.text)
```